# How to set OIDC/OAuth bearer token in C# HttpClient when flowing client subject

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, identityserver3, openid-connect

As I understand it HttpClient has been designed to be created once and reused. I am using IdentityServer3 as an OIDC/OAuth server and the samples I have looked at create a HttpClient per request and set the bearer token using an extension method:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.SetBearerToken(token);
```

SetBearerToken simply sets the default authorization header on a HttpClient:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = 
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
```

I have a ASP.NET web application calling a ASP.NET Web API and I have configured them so that client identity flows to the API when a call is made, i.e when configuring OpenId connect authentication I set:

```
OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions.ResponseType = "id_token token"
```

However, if the subject claim is passed in the token I can't now reuse the HttpClient (a request could have its authorization header overwritten before it is sent by another request for example).

If I want to reuse a HttpClient should I be setting the token into a HttpRequestMessage? If not what is the recommended pattern for handling this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will definitely want to create your own [HttpRequestMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage(v=vs.118).aspx) and use [SendAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138176%28v=vs.118%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Unfortunately, you will not have the extension method for setting the bearer token, but it is the best way to handle the HttpClient.

Comment: I suspected that would be the answer. I am using HttpClientExtensions so I can use HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync. Is there a HttpRequestMessageExtensions with similar JSON handling extension methods or do I have to roll my own?

Comment: Not that I've seen in a formal library, I'm afraid. So far everyone has been stuck writing their own boilerplate using serialized JSON in [StringContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.stringcontent(v=vs.118).aspx).